# Is there any way to filter/search emails by received time only, regardless of date?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, email-filter

I'm basicly trying to filter emails I received after working time. Date isn't important that much but need to filter them by delivery hour. Adding hour column didn't work but not sure I setted format correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not feasible to directly search for all messages received after working time. You may consider using the following sample to search day by day(Modify the date as appropriate):

Let's say you want to search the messages received between 9/3/2018 18:00 and 9/4/2018 09:00, you can type the text below in the instant search box:

**received:>=9/3/2018 18:00 AND received:<= 9/4/2018 09:00**
[image]